# LCK information on Linux

Tags: linux, memory, command, profiling, bandwidth

The `prstat` command in Solaris has the "LCK" field - essentially the time that a process or thread waited for a user-level lock. What can I use in Linux to get the same information? I looked at `top`, `htop` and `pstree` but none output something like the LCK.

The bottomline is that I would like to replicate this profiling method: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/mem-alloc-1557798.html, but this time on Linux.

Comment: Linux have no direct accounting of user-level locking; but if user thread locks and waits on some resource, `futex` syscall is made to put the thread to sleep. You can check for high contention on locks with "usr" and "sys" times of threads in top (press H to see all threads); or you can use `perf` with events from scheduler or even with kprobe on futex. There is introduction to profiling on linux from Brendan Gregg: http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-11-22/linux-perf-tools-2014.html